# MySQL MAX and MIN function return unexpected values

Tags: mysql

I use this SQL request :

```
SELECT MAX(valeur), MIN(valeur) FROM liste_caracteristiques as L WHERE idCarac = '1'
```

idCarac = 1 is the weight of a product, I will use JOIN, but to explain my problem I simplified the query

On this table :

```
|idCarac|int(11)
|refproduit|int(11)
|valeur|varchar(255)

|1|8957|3
|1|9980|1200
|2|8957|8.3cm
|2|9980|15cm
```

The result is : MAX(valeur) = 3 and MIN(valeur) = 1200

And I can't understand why

e : The max value is the minimal value, and the minimal value is the maximal value

Comment: What 'unexpected' values are you getting?

Comment: The max value is the minimal value, and the minimal value is the maximal value

Comment: The type of the `valuer` column is `varchar`, i.e. string. The values are compared using the dictionary order. `1200` comes before `3` in the dictionary, for sure. If you store numbers in the column then change its type to `int` and move the measure of unit (`cm`) into a separate column.

Comment: @axiac aaah ok I understand now, but I can't change the type because I am not only stocking weight in this column

Comment: Maybe I should get the Max and the Min values with PHP

Comment: As strings, `'1200' < '15cm' < '3' < '8.3cm'`. Not useful for sorting.

Comment: In this table I also got 'Android', 'iOS' ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the values of valeur

```
SELECT MAX(CAST (valeur AS INT)), MIN(CAST (valeur AS INT)) 
FROM liste_caracteristiques as L 
WHERE idCarac = '1'
```